# google cloud storage per file statistics/downloads

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to get per file statistics (or at least download count) for files in google cloud  storage?

I want to find the number of downloads for a js plugin file to get an idea of how frequently these are used (in client pages).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it has to be enabled.

The official recommendation is to create another bucket for the logs generated by the main bucket that you want to trace.

```
gsutil mb gs://<some-unique-prefix>-example-logs-bucket
```

then assign Cloud Storage the roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter role for the bucket:

```
gsutil iam ch group:cloud-storage-analytics@google.com:legacyBucketWriter gs://<some-unique-prefix>-example-logs-bucket
```

and finally enable the logging for your main bucket:

```
gsutil logging set on -b gs://example-logs-bucket gs://<main-bucket>
```

Generate some activity on your main bucket, then wait for one hour at most, hence the reports are generated hourly and daily. You will be able to browse these events on the logs-bucket created at step 1:

[image: logs-files-saved-in-aux-bucket]

More info, can be found at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, using [Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logging) is now recommended instead of using [legacyBucketWriter](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#should-you-use).

Logging to a separate Cloud Storage bucket with legacyBucketWriter produces csv files, which you would have to then load into BigQuery yourself to make them actionable, and this would be done far from in real time.  Cloud Audit Logs are easier to set up and work with by comparison, and logs are delivered almost instantly.